# using R: how to parse text colors (rgb) from cells with conditional formatting rules in xlsm file

Tags: r

I have an .xlsm file with a sheet where the text color of the cells is determined by conditional formatting.

I want to open that file in R and get the rgb color of the text in the cells.

I've looked at multiple packages: `xlsx`, `openxlsx` and `tidyxl`, but none of them seem to be able to parse text colors from cells with conditional formatting

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to achieve it in R?

Comment: Did you try [tidyxl::xlsx_formats()](https://nacnudus.github.io/tidyxl/reference/xlsx_formats.html)?

Comment: yes, I did. It doesn't seem to work for conditional formatted cells.

Comment: Conditional formatting is simply a set of rules applied dynamically to the worksheet by the spreadsheet software. Is it not part of the cells style information. You have to figure out which set of rules is applied to which cells and recreate the rules in R. Since there are many possible rules (predefined and custom), there is no single solution. You can have a look at the conditional formatting in R if you load the workbook in e.g. `openxlsx2` and inspect `wb$worksheets[[1]]$conditionalFormatting`.

Comment: @JanMarvin This wb$worksheets[[1]]$conditionalFormatting allows me to see indeed the existing conditional formatting rules that exist on the sheet , but not which rule was applied to each cell.

Comment: Have a look at the openxml 2.8.1 API reference for [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.conditionalformatting?view=openxml-2.8.1). This should get you started.